# If I have 2 object objects and their Type how can I get their value?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code:

```
Type type = typeof(T);

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    Type dataType = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetType();
    object oldValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(originalVals, null);
    object newValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(newVals, null);

    if (oldValue != newValue)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

The 2 variables originalVals and newVals that I am using are Linq2Sql classes.  If 1 has an int field (intField) with an id of 999 and the other has the same field with the same value the oldValue != newValue comparison will pass because it will, obviously, use reference equality.

I'd like to know how to cast oldValue and newValue as the Type stored in dataType, something like:

```
((typeof(dataType)oldValue); or
(dataType)oldValue;
```

but this isn't working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think on dataType you want to do .GetPropertyType()

Comment: Some one else has suggested using .PropertyType, so which should it be...? .PropertyType, .GetPropertyType() or .GetType()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if(!oldValue.Equals(newValue))` or `if(!Object.Equals(oldValue, newValue))` instead of !=

Comment: Cheers, if(!Object.Equals(oldValue, newValue)) seems to have done the trick!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For objects, the == and != operators just check if the *references* are the same: do they point to the same object?

You want to use the `.Equals()` method to check for value equivalence.

```
if (!oldvalue.Equals(newvalue))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the references are different.  I thought .Equals() checks for reference equality too...?

Comment: .Equals() will _fall back on_ reference equality by default, which is different.  Though you might be right in this case that this will be what happens.

Comment: [continued] in which case you might be stuck using the 'MakeGenericType()` method to build an EqualityComparer<T> object to do the compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if they implement the `IComparable` interface and use that to do the comparison.

```
IComparable comparable = newValue as IComparable;
if(comparable.CompareTo(oldValue) != 0)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`Convert.ChangeType(oldValue, dataType)`

This should cast `oldValue` to the type represented by `dataType`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this first of all

```
Type dataType = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).PropertyType;
```

This will give you the type of the data for the property. What you have is getting you a type for the instance of PropertyInfo.